# Docking QGIS Plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

How to dock QGIS plugin window? I am trying

```
self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dlg)
```

in `run` method of QGIS Plugin Implementation class, but the dialog keeps appearing as a floating window.
`dlg` is an instance of class inheriting from `QtWidgets.QDockWidget`

Comment: Maybe you disabled docking capability of the dockwidget.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this `run` method for my widget :

```py
def run(self):
    """Run method that loads and starts the plugin"""

    if not self.pluginIsActive:
        self.pluginIsActive = True

        if self.dockwidget == None:
            # Create the dockwidget (after translation) and keep reference
            self.dockwidget = FastFieldFillerDockWidget(self.iface)

        # connect to provide cleanup on closing of dockwidget
        self.dockwidget.closingPlugin.connect(self.onClosePlugin)

        # show the dockwidget
        self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.dockwidget)
        self.dockwidget.show()
```